# Gradle: Test Java library on Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, testing

(I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70980178/github-ci-run-pure-java-tests-on-android) earlier, so I'll try a more general form and see if anybody knows how to do that.)  There's [a Java library](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) to which I have added [patches for Android support](https://github.com/Erhannis/tls-channel/tree/feature/android_support).  I would like to automate testing of the code, but in order to check if it runs properly on Android, I need to test it on Android.  The library artifact is a jar, though, not an AAR or an APK, so I don't want to remove the old build modes, and so far my attempts to add the Gradle Android Plugin yields errors like `The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.`

How can I continue to produce a plain Java jar, but also automatically test it on Android?  Do I need to, like, make a new submodule or something specifically for the tests?

Comment: Yes, usually it's a good practice to create a new module, say `integration-tests`, which in itself is an android library/app, and then you'd include your JAR/java lib in there and run android tests.

Comment: @romtsn Well, I think that got me one step closer to success.  (Now I guess need to figure out how to rerun the tests-in-scala as android instrumented tests.)  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: sure. You could post a new question with your current problem btw.

Comment: @romtsn True, and I have: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71195281/513038 .  Lemme know if you have any wisdom there, too, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, usually it's a good practice to create a new module, say `integration-tests`, which in itself is an android library/app, and then you'd include your JAR/java lib in there and run android tests over it.