# Run scala tests on Android

Tags: java, android, scala, unit-testing, testing

(Sequel to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71154126/gradle-test-java-library-on-android).)  There's [a Java library](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) to which I have added [patches for Android support](https://github.com/Erhannis/tls-channel/tree/feature/android_support).  I would like to automate testing of the code, but in order to check if it runs properly on Android, I need to test it on Android.  (Current progress [here](https://github.com/erhannis/tls-channel/tree/feature/android_ci).)  I've moved the main code into a "java" module, and created an "android" module to run the Android instrumented tests (tests that run on a device or emulator).  Now, I'd really prefer to run all the normal tests again but on Android (so nobody has to rewrite all the tests and keep them up-to-date), by e.g. adding a line to the gradle file or creating a symbolic link, but so far I haven't found a gradle command to do it, and a symbolic link did nothing that I could see.  Part of the problem, I think, is that the tests are in Scala.  Is there a way to run Scala tests as instrumented tests on Android?  (Or another way of equivalently solving the problem without a ton of recurring work?)  The easiest probably-doable way that's occurred to me is to add a test in Android that manually calls the other tests (e.g. `com.whatever.Tests.testThatThing();`), but that requires maintenance as tests are created/removed, and I'm not sure there won't be problems with like, tests not being exported for external use or something.